# Use content variable as HTML tag

Tags: jquery

I have a generic function to get data and disable an another HTML tag :

```
function Testing(htmlData, htmlResult) {
    //here I'd like get the value of htmldata (it's a tag name)
}
```

I call this function like this :

```
<input type="text" id="MyTextBox" />
<input type="text" id="MyTextBoxResult" />
$("#MyTextBox").blur(function () {
    Testing("MyTextBox", "MyTextBoxResult");
});
```

Comment: you say in your comment that you call 'Testing' with the tag name, but after you call it with the tag id 'MyTextBox'. So what do you really want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Testing(htmlData, htmlResult) {
    var valueOfHtmlData = $('#' + htmlData).val();
}
```

But you could also pass the jQuery object directly to your function

```
$("#MyTextBox").blur(function () {
    Testing($(this), "MyTextBoxResult");
});
```

and your function would be

```
function Testing(htmlData, htmlResult) {
    var valueOfHtmlData = htmlData.val();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("#" + htmlData).val()` will get the value of the element with an `id` of the value of `htmlData`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. Gets the value of the firsts and disables the second. Test it on fiddle

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#MyTextBox").blur(function () {
        Testing('MyTextBox','MyTextBoxResult');
    });
     function Testing(htmlData, htmlResult) {
           alert( $('#'+htmlData).val());
         $('#'+htmlResult).attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    }   

    });
```